# Batch: Using lookup file to search directory tree and move files

Tags: batch-file, move

My query resolves around a large directory of images, with a complex series of sub-directories, and needing to perform a lookup for a list of files, and moving said files.

I have found a few possible solutions to my request on StackOverflow and other support forums and here is my current solution:

```
@echo off
set Source=C:\users\directory
set Target=C:\users\target
set FileList=C:\users\lookup\list.txt
echo.

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto Exit
if not exist "%Target%" md "%Target%"

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do move "%Source%\%%a" "%Target%"

:Exit
echo.
echo press the Space Bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

This works perfectly fine but only targets the parent directory. How can I have this Batch script search top down from the parent directory and find all matching files provided in the lookup list?

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('type "%FileList%"') do for /F "delims=" %%b in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "%Source%\%%a"') do move "%%b" "%Target%"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of your code including the solution to search the source directory recursively. For this I assumed that the **target directory is flat**, so no sub-directories are to be copied from the source directory. So here is the code:

```bat
@echo off
set "Source=C:\users\directory"
set "Target=C:\users\target"
set "FileList=C:\users\lookup\list.txt"
echo/

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto :Quit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto :Quit
2> nul md "%Target%"

for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ("%FileList%") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%b in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "%Source%\%%a"') do (
        move "%%b" "%Target%"
    )
)

:Quit
echo/
echo Press the Space bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

Besides some minor syntax improvements, the major change is the additional nested `for /F %%b` loop, which parses the output of a `dir` command, which in turn searches for each file name given by `%%a` also in the sub-directories of the source directory.

---

In case you want the respective sub-directories in the source directory to be copied to the target directory, so the **target directory is recursive**, the script needs to be adapted:

```
@echo off
set "Source=C:\users\directory"
set "Target=C:\users\target"
set "FileList=C:\users\lookup\list.txt"
echo/

if not exist "%Source%" echo Source folder "%Source%" not found & goto :Quit
if not exist "%FileList%" echo File list "%FileList%" not found & goto :Quit
for /D %%d in ("%Source%") do set "Source=%%~fd"
2> nul md "%Target%"

for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ("%FileList%") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%b in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "%Source%\%%a"') do (
        set "Item=%%b"
        set "Parent=%%~dpb."
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "Parent=!Parent:*%Source%=.!"
        2> nul md "!Target!\!Parent!"
        move "!Item!" "!Target!\!Parent!"
        endlocal
    )
)

:Quit
echo/
echo Press the Space bar to close this window.
pause > nul
```

This is what I did:

- added line `for /D %%d in ("%Source%") do set "Source=%%~fd"`, which does nothing but get the full absolute and resolved path to the source directory from the given one; this is necessary because there are some string manipulations done on paths (for instance, `C:\USERS\.\directory` is equivalent to `C:\Users\any\..\Directory` as a path, although they are different strings; the `for /D` command line resolves such paths to `C:\users\directory`);
- inside of the `for /F %%b` loop, `%%b` is stored in variable `Item`, which constitutes a full path; `Parent`stores the full path to the parent directory with `\.` appended; for example, if the current item is `C:\users\directory\subdir\file.ext`, `Parent` holds `C:\users\directory\subdir\.`;
- [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled, because the variables `Item` and `Parent` are set *and* read within the same block of code; it is not generally enabled but toggled in the loop in order not to cause any trouble when exclamation marks occur in the paths;
- the line `set "Parent=!Parent:*%Source%=!"` removes the source directory trom the path stored in `Parent`; for example, the `Parent` path `C:\users\directory\subdir\.` becomes `.\subdir\.` when the source directory is `C:\users\directory`, so the `Parent` becomes relative;
- `2> nul md "!Target!\!Parent!"` ensures that the `Parent` directory exists in the target directory (`2> nul` suppresses a potential error message);
- finally, the movement is done; for example, when the current item is `C:\users\directory\subdir\file.ext` and the target directory is `C:\users\target`, it is moved into the directory `C:\users\target\.\subdir\.`, which is equivalent to `C:\users\target\subdir`;

Note that the **source directory must not contain any `!` and `=`** characters for the script to work!